# trying to drag something using a JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jlayeredpane

I'm trying to put a drag-n-drop operation into a program of mine; I found the following example that illustrates a lot of what I'm trying to do:

```
    package sandbox;
    
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.Cursor;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.LayoutManager;
    import java.awt.Point;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
    
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    
    /**
     * Example showing the use of a JLayeredPane to implement dragging an object
     * across a JPanel containing other objects.
     * <P>
     * Basic idea: Create a JLayeredPane as a container, then put the JPanel containing
     * the application's components or whatever in the JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER layer of that layered pane.
     * The code is going to drag a JComponent object by calling JComponent.setPosition(x,y)
     * on the component. When a mouse is clicked on the panel to start the dragging, put the
     * component on the drag layer of the layered pane; as it is dragged, continue to call
     * setPosition to move it. When the mouse is released, use the x.y position of the release
     * to decide what to do with it next.   
     * 
     */
    public class ChessBoard extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
    {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        JLayeredPane layeredPane;
        JPanel chessBoard;
        JLabel chessPiece;
        int xAdjustment;
        int yAdjustment;
    
        public ChessBoard()
        {
            Dimension boardSize = new Dimension(600, 600);
    
            //  Use a Layered Pane for this application
    
            layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
            layeredPane.setPreferredSize( boardSize );
            layeredPane.addMouseListener( this );
            layeredPane.addMouseMotionListener( this );
            getContentPane().add(layeredPane);
            
            //debug
            LayoutManager lm = layeredPane.getLayout();
            System.out.println("Layered pane layout name is " + (lm == null? "<null>" : lm.getClass().getName()));
    
            //  Add a chess board to the Layered Pane on the DEFAULT layer
            chessBoard = new JPanel();
            chessBoard.setLayout( new GridLayout(8, 8) );
            chessBoard.setPreferredSize( boardSize );
            chessBoard.setBounds(0, 0, boardSize.width, boardSize.height);
            layeredPane.add(chessBoard, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    
            //  Build the Chess Board squares
            // We use an 8x8 grid, and put a JPanel with BorderLayout on each square. 
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    JPanel square = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
                    square.setBackground( (i + j) % 2 == 0 ? Color.gray : Color.white );
                    chessBoard.add( square );
                }
            }
    
            // Add a few pieces to the board
            // we do this with an ImageIcon that gets added to the square's panel.
            ImageIcon duke = new ImageIcon("granary.gif");  // this is the image to add to each space.
            addDuke(duke, 0);
            addDuke(duke, 6);
            addDuke(duke, 15);
            addDuke(duke, 20);
        }
        
        private void addDuke(ImageIcon duke, int boardPosition)
        {
          JLabel pieceLabel = new JLabel(duke);
          JPanel piecePanel = (JPanel)chessBoard.getComponent(boardPosition);
          piecePanel.add(pieceLabel);
        }
    
        /*
        **  Add the selected chess piece to the dragging layer so it can be moved
        */
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
          // get the component where the user pressed; iff that's not a panel,
          // we'll put it on the dragging layer.
            chessPiece = null;                                         // change1 swap the change1 lines
            // chessPiece = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("house1x1.gif")); // change1

            Component c =  chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
    
            if (c instanceof JPanel) return;
    
            // get the location of the panel containing the image panel, i.e.,
            // the square's panel. we adjust the location to which we move the
            // piece by this amount so the piece doesn't 'snap to' the cursor 
            // location.
            Point parentLocation = c.getParent().getLocation();
            xAdjustment = parentLocation.x - e.getX();
            yAdjustment = parentLocation.y - e.getY();
            chessPiece = (JLabel)c; // change2 - comment out
            chessPiece.setLocation(e.getX() + xAdjustment, e.getY() + yAdjustment);
    
            layeredPane.add(chessPiece, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER); // evidently this removes it from the default layer also.
            layeredPane.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
        }
    
        /*
        **  Move the chess piece around
        */
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
        {
            if (chessPiece == null) return;
    
            //  The drag location should be within the bounds of the chess board
    
            int x = me.getX() + xAdjustment;
            int xMax = layeredPane.getWidth() - chessPiece.getWidth();
            x = Math.min(x, xMax);
            x = Math.max(x, 0);
    
            int y = me.getY() + yAdjustment;
            int yMax = layeredPane.getHeight() - chessPiece.getHeight();
            y = Math.min(y, yMax);
            y = Math.max(y, 0);
    
            chessPiece.setLocation(x, y);   // evidently this works for whatever layer contains the piece.
            // also, the layout manager of its new home is evidently not the same as lower layers.
         }
    
        /*
        **  Drop the chess piece back onto the chess board
        */
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
            layeredPane.setCursor(null);
    
            if (chessPiece == null) return;
    
            //  Make sure the chess piece is no longer painted on the layered pane
    
            chessPiece.setVisible(false);
            layeredPane.remove(chessPiece);
            chessPiece.setVisible(true);
    
            //  The drop location should be within the bounds of the chess board
    
            int xMax = layeredPane.getWidth() - chessPiece.getWidth();
            int x = Math.min(e.getX(), xMax);
            x = Math.max(x, 0);
    
            int yMax = layeredPane.getHeight() - chessPiece.getHeight();
            int y = Math.min(e.getY(), yMax);
            y = Math.max(y, 0);
    
            Component c =  chessBoard.findComponentAt(x, y);
            Container parent = null;
            if (c instanceof JLabel)
            {
                parent = c.getParent(); // there's a piece on the square already; remove it from the panel.
                parent.remove(0);
            }
            else
            {
                parent = (Container)c;
            }
            parent.add( chessPiece );     // this adds the piece back to the default layer
            parent.validate();
        }
    
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            JFrame frame = new ChessBoard();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
            frame.setResizable( false );
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
            frame.setVisible(true);
         }
    }
```

This does the job for the case of a chessboard, namely allowing a user to drag any of the pieces on the chessboard to a different square.

In the application I'm writing, the item being dragged doesn't exist until the user clicks something that starts the dragging operation. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that creation and have it show up.

My current attempt is on lines labelled 'change1' and 'change2'; you swap the two lines with 'change1', and comment out the one with 'change2'. In other words, create the JLabel when the mouse is pressed, and (hopefully) drag that around. But when I run that, the image does not show up on press or during dragging, but DOES show up on the square at the end of the drag.

What have I missed here? I am a little confused by JLayeredPane, the javadoc says that it will follow layout rules, but not whether the layout rules apply to all the components on all layers, or just the bottom, or to all layers but separately, what? I wouldn't think it was a layout issue, but I don't know what's wrong. Do I need some kind of UI update somewhere? I thought adding the component would invalidate the panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code was written assuming you were clicking on a chess piece.

Now you want to click on an empty cell which will require the following changes.

1. The chess board consists of JPanels in each cell. Some cells will contain a JLabel represent a chess piece. The current logic in the mousePressed event is expecting you to click on a JLabel otherwise some processing is skipped.

You need to remove:

```
//if (c instanceof JPanel) return;
```

2. By default a Swing component has a 0 size when it is created.

You need to give it a size:

```
chessPiece.setSize( chessPiece.getPreferredSize() );
```

3. The positioning logic for the label is based on finding the location of the clicked component relative to the parent. Since there is no label, this logic is now based on the panel relative to the layered pane.

You need to adjust this logic to make it relative to parent panel again:

```
//Point parentLocation = c.getParent().getLocation();
Point parentLocation = c.getLocation();
```

My updated mousePressed method looks like:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
  // get the component where the user pressed; iff that's not a panel,
  // we'll put it on the dragging layer.
    //chessPiece = null;                                         // change1 swap the change1 lines
    chessPiece = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("dukewavered.gif")); // change1
    chessPiece.setSize( chessPiece.getPreferredSize() );

    Component c =  chessBoard.findComponentAt(e.getX(), e.getY());

    //if (c instanceof JPanel) return;

    // get the location of the panel containing the image panel, i.e.,
    // the square's panel. we adjust the location to which we move the
    // piece by this amount so the piece doesn't 'snap to' the cursor
    // location.
    //Point parentLocation = c.getParent().getLocation();
    Point parentLocation = c.getLocation();
    xAdjustment = parentLocation.x - e.getX();
    yAdjustment = parentLocation.y - e.getY();
    //chessPiece = (JLabel)c; // change2 - comment out
    chessPiece.setLocation(e.getX() + xAdjustment, e.getY() + yAdjustment);

    layeredPane.add(chessPiece, JLayeredPane.DRAG_LAYER); // evidently this removes it from the default layer also.
    layeredPane.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
}
```

Note the above changes will break the old functionality of being able to drag an existing label. If you need functionality for both then your logic will be determined on whether you click on a JLabel (in which case you use the old logic) or click on a JPanel (in which case you use the newer logic).

Comment: GREAT explanations. As it turned out, what I wanted was simpler, but because you explained what was behind the changes in logic you thought I wanted, I was able to do something *different* than that, which is why I prefer having an explanation to having *only* an example.